# How to webpack just include js without change file?

Tags: webpack

Example:
in `main.js`

```
import {test} from "./test.js"
// other code
test();
```

in `test.js`

```
export var test= (function () { console.log("test")};
```

it result `bundle.js`

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
....
....
```

what i want just like this

```
//other code
var test= (function () { console.log("test")};
```

After I write that 2 file (`main.js` and `test.js`), 
surely I write webpack config file `webpack.config.js` with this simple code :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

Then in console I run `webpack` command which generated file name  `bundle.js`.

And I open `bundle.js` with text editor and get result like above code.

How to webpack just include js without change file?

Comment: If you don't want webpack to do what it's designed for - just don't use it. You better explain *why* you need that, since apparently your attempt is not so right.

Comment: becasue I just want use export and import feature for now.

Comment: Your "what i want just like this" does not correlate with initial examples. Can you provide a complete accurate desired result?

Comment: I've read this three times and have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: You may want to look at rollupjs.

Comment: I update my description hope make it clear.

Comment: You cannot make it "like that" with webpack. And it's still not obvious what's wrong with the bundle webpack generates.

Comment: If you want really that, you should use `CopyWebpackPlugin` and not include your `main.js` file in the `entry` parameter.